# Showing messages both by application and by tag in LogCat?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat, android-logcat

I have an Android application I am working on. It outputs debug info and errors to LogCat.

Now, I use some of my debug-helper classes that are usable in other projects also. So, I have them output the messages with their own tags instead of the application's.

I have the messages filtered mostly by the application. This shows both the application's own tag and the other tags.

Also, I know I can use bar characters `|` to filter multiple tags. This is also nice for hiding random messages from the system with tags like `SensorManager` or `dalvikvm`, as only my tags are shown.

Now, if an error occurs that is not caught at all by my application, it has the tag `AndroidRuntime` in LogCat. Also, I have seen error messages with *no* application name info, just PID and a tag.

What I want here is to filter messages like

```
app:my.application.package OR tag:MyApp|MyDebugClass
```

Is this possible with ADT LogCat in Eclipse?

Comment: The filter uses RegEx. So yes.

Comment: @wtsang02 And how would I do that?